# Jqgrid set cell background color

Tags: jquery, colors, jqgrid

In "Custom data tooltips in **jqGrid 3.4**" discussion, came to know how to use `setcell` to change the color of the text inside a cell of jqgrid. How can we change the background color of the cell?

Tried the following

```
jQuery("#list").setCell (row,col,'',{ background-color:'red'});

jQuery("#list").setCell (row,col,'','',{ bgcolor:'red'};
```

Answer (score 13):

Use **background** instead of specific rules like background-color:

```
jQuery("#list").setCell (row,col,val,{background:'#ff0000'});
```

Comment: Why?? whats wrong with using background-color?? Please share that info as well

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing wrong with it, other than it's slightly less intuitive than the rest of the jQGrid api.  Looks like specific rules such as background color must be passed in quotes, for example: $("#list").setCell (row,col,val,{'background-color':'red'});

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery("#list").setCell (row,col,'',{ 'background-color':'red'})
```

This did not work in IE for me (fine in firefox and chrome), so I did what Jon Weers suggested and switched to:

```
jQuery("#list").setCell (row,col,'',{'background':'#ff0000'});
```

and this worked in firefox, chrome, and IE for me.

Sorry, my account is too new to vote up, or apparently comment, otherwise I'd simply vote up Jon's post.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#list').setCell('12','name','',{'background-color': 'red'},'');
```

Are you putting the right row id? The right colName?

You are also missing the quotes in background-color.

Comment: Agree about css, but I'd use a jqGrid custom formatter to add a class to the td and then build the CSS around classes, not position. Remember, there are plug-ins which allow users to re-order columns!

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: I changed my answer to use the method provided by sachin. When the users re-order columns the grid is generated again and it looses all it's classes.